# knitr/Rmd: page break after n lines/n distance

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

***Let me caveat by saying that this may be better suited as an html/css question but (a) I'm not too familiar with those techniques and (b) I wanted to keep it all in the family (R family) if possible.***

I would like to use `knitr` to write academic style reports (**APA 6 type guidelines**) using Rmarkdown.  I've got most aspects worked out but not page breaking.  I can manually set page breaks with something like:

````
# report

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
```
------
## Page 1

```{r plot1}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```
------
## Page 2
````

In the following .Rmd I'd like to programatically set those breaks after n lines/n distance.  So let's say after 8 inches or 140 lines.

````
# report

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
```
Initial Text. Yay!

```{r plot1}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

More Text.  Outstanding.  What Hadley's not calling it plyr2?

```{r plot2, fig.width=4, fig.height=4}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

`r paste(rep("So much text so little time!", 10000))`
````

How can I programatically set page breaks after n distance.  This is similar to how `LaTeX` would break a file into pages so if a figure takes too much space it would be forced to the next page.

**EDIT** Found this from a friend: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/  may be helpful.

Comment: My guess is the solution does not exsit, but I'll be thrilled if it does! It sounds like reinventing LaTeX with HTML...

Comment: I'm finding this out in asking HTML people and they propose that it can be done using java as an intermediary that calculates the length of each html page.  I am writing a paper right now that argues for the need to do this and when it's done (it will be in html but with breaks by hand) I'll get the prototype up and maybe if people are interested a team could get together to take on the challenge.

Comment: @TylerRinker Do you mean javascript?  Note that java and javascript are not the same.

Comment: yes I do mean that.  I always say java when I mean javascript because of my lack a familiarity with the terms/use.

Comment: @TylerRinker I'm not after badges. I'm improving the legibility of the description.

Comment: What is the reason for this? To reduce page download sizes, or for navigation?

Comment: aesthetics/navigation.  I'm, as Yihui alluded to, interested in academic papers that utilize HTML but keep the aesthetics of LaTeX pdf.  I've actually made a prototype paper like this but the line breaks automatically was a problem.  Also justifying works well except for the last sentence on each page.

Comment: @TylerRinker: are you also interested in post-processing the file? Do you need separate files for each page or just adding in `------`? BTW which markdown format do support page break? :) I really miss that feature from Pandoc.

Comment: @daroczig My thought is one file.  I have already done this in a paper using a white `<div>` tags to separate "pages".  As far as post processing what do you mean?  You can feed a style.css to knitr + RStudio already so I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: @TylerRinker: I thought of post-processing the markdown file **before** converting to HTML like adding `------` after each n lines. I am just not sure if you are after this workaround. If so, it can be done in a jiffy.

Comment: Yeah that's how I approached it (or something similar).  I'm looking to be automatic (as it's difficult to tell n lines when figures get thrown into the mix).  Ideally the solution would work like LaTeX when it creates a pdf.

Comment: I see, thank you @TylerRinker for the clarification. Could you please share the link og the "prototype paper" for a demo?

Comment: For page breaking I'm using just standard LaTeX expression: `/newpage`. New page after n lines would be just inserting `/vspace*{10cm}` (the vspace size depends how many n lines would you like to skip) and after that straight `/newpage. I'm I missing something?

Comment: @Max this is Rmd/html not tex/Rnw.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically. Create an HTML div. Set this div's width and height to a fixed amount and the overflow to scroll.

```
<div style="height:1000px; width: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    ...
</div>
```

Process your markdown into HTML elements. I have 5 `h1` tags that are 300px tall each.

```
<h1 style="height:300px;">First</h1>
<h1 style="height:300px;">Second</h1>
<h1 style="height:300px;">Third</h1>
<h1 style="height:300px;">Fourth</h1>
<h1 style="height:300px;">Fifth</h1>
```

These 5 `h1` wont all fit on the same page. The page is only 1,000 pixels tall. Only 3 `h1` tags will fit on this page. We'll need to insert a pagebreak after the third element.

Incrementally add each new item into the DOM. After inserting each item check to see if the browser's scroll bar is present. If it is, then we know that the item we just inserted was too big for this page; remove the item and insert a page break.

Before:

```
### First
### Second
### Third
### Fourth
### Fifth
```

After:

```
### First
### Second
### Third
------
### Fourth
### Fifth
```

This would work for any element and you wouldn't have to worry about an item's height. Because, if the item you just inserted made the HTML div scroll then we need a page break. Images, videos, h1, h2, p, custom/dynamic css, anything.

**UPDATE**

You could also calculate the height of each div element. http://api.jquery.com/height/ That way recalculating a 54 page document would be much easier.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, this requires manually "fixing" I (and those who upvoted) are looking for a way to programatically accomplish this  in the way that Latex does this with a pdf.  I mean we can manually set page breaks in Latex but undertakes this for you (in a relatively smart way).  That being said the approach you offer (and I currently use) is poor because let's say you delete/add a paragraph on page 3 of a 54 page paper.  that means every subsequent page will be effected.

Comment: "...is poor because let's say you delete/add a paragraph on page 3 of a 54 page paper. that means every subsequent page will be effected." - I updated my answer with a more efficient solution but I see no way around having to recalculate the remaining X pages after a change is made.